# Is it possible to play audio through Bluetooth and AUX at the same time while playing different audio on each?

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth

Is it possible to play audio through Bluetooth and AUX (3.5mm audio jack) at the same time while playing different audio on each? I'm using Linux Mint 20 on a desktop "Gaming" pc and I'm trying to hook up my speaker and Bluetooth headphones in a way so I can listen to my own music on the headphones and then play some other through the speakers.

The way I was thinking about it was if I have 2 separate audio applications running and then select them and redirect their output. Is something like possible, or at least a way to play 2 different sources of audio to two different outputs using one machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the [PulseAudio GUI Mixer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio) on my Manjoro system - this allows you to select the sound device output for each application.